# DVD shows empty after burn is complete

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

I burn data on DVD-R. The burning process goes well and at the end I get the message that it was successful. But when I insert the burned DVD it shows nothing, used space - 0 bytes, free space - 0 bytes. It is reading previously burned data DVD and other CDs. I used Ashampoo free burning 6, Nero Lite and today used CDburnerXP. My laptop is Windows 7 ultimate 64, Intel i3. I doubt this is due to KIS 2012. About a month ago I was using Avast free and back then there was no such burning or reading issue.

Comment: Will it let you attempt to burn to the disk again, or does it think it's got data?   When you look at the DVD-R does it look like it's been burned to?